# Angular Material Table custom typography level

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

What's the best way to change typography level of material table based on screen size?

I tried following material theme mixing

```
_mat-table.scss
--------------------------------
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use 'sass:map';

@mixin theme($theme) {
  $typography: map.get($theme, typography);

  .mat-mdc-table {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
        @include mat.typography-level($typography, 'caption');
    }

  }
}
```

However the value gets overwrite by inner mat table styles coming from `_data-table.scss`

```
  .mdc-data-table__content {
    @include typography.typography(body2, $query: $query);
  }
```

[image: applied css styles]

Comment: Why don't you use the `mat.table-typography()` mixin?

Comment: I do `@include mat.table-typography(atomic.$theme);`. That one applies the typography from my theme. But I want to change the typography on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

to apply to all inner elements of the table need to use *

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1023.98px) {
      * {
        @include mat.typography-level($typography, 'caption');
      }
    }
```